# I missed a cred and can't find out where?

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

The error Uncaught ReferenceError: cred is not defined at navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition.maximumAge

I can’t understand where I missed a cred ... please tell me

```
//get current user

  let user = firebase.auth().currentUser
  console.log

//get current location

if(navigator.geolocation){
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(pos => {
    this.lat = pos.coords.latitude
    this.lng = pos.coords.longitude

    // find the user record and then update geocoords

    db.collection('users').where('user_id', '==', cred.user.uid).get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.id)
      })
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

The error pretty much says it all: cred is not defined at the line

```
db.collection('users').where('user_id', '==', cred.user.uid).get()
```

From you code I suspect you should be using instead:

```
db.collection('users').where('user_id', '==', user.uid).get()
```